# How to add new parameters when extends MRTask

Tags: scala, h2o

I wrote a Miss Class to extends MRTask to check missing values in a H2oFrame. This is what I did

```
package org.apache.spark.h2o.utils

import water.fvec.{NewChunk, Frame, Chunk}
import water._

class Miss extends MRTask[Log] {
  override def map(c: Chunk, nc: NewChunk): Unit = {
    for (row <- 0 until c.len()) {
      if(c.atd(row).isNaN){
        nc.addNum(0)
      }
      else 
      nc.addNum(1)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, here when a row is NaN we can get 0 in new column. If I want to use a number other than 0 to mark missing value, I have to change my code to do it. Can I just add a new parameter X in my Miss Class? When I call this class I can just write something like

```
H2OFrame.add(new Miss(8).doAll(1, pred.vec(0)).outputFrame(Array("Miss"), null))
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I know nothing about h20\sparkling water. But you could define your class as `class Miss(num: Double) extends...`

Comment: Appreciate for your help! Let me try! : )

Comment: @Odomontois Thanks for your help. It works perfect.